# passing laravel orm to view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm working with laravel 4 and am unsure about the best practice-- is it considered a good idea to pass the Eloquent object directly to the view, or is it best to use the `toArray` method on it before passing it in?

Eg. this:

```
public function index()
{
    $users  = Users::all();
    return View::make('users.index', array('users' => $users));
}
```

or this:

```
public function index()
{
    $users  = Users::all()->toArray();
    return View::make('users.index', array('users' => $users));
}
```

or something else entirely?

Comment: I would suggest using presenter that will wrap the data you want to pass to the view. Then it doesn't matter what it is (Eloquent/Array/StdObject) and your views are not tighly coupled to the type they get. If you want to change this type, simply adjust your presenter, and templates remain unchanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending the view just the object is perfectly acceptable and is what is encouraged in most cases.

```
return View::make('users.index')->with(array('users' => $users));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think making an array from the object and wrapping it in another to pass to the view is an overhead, when you can directly pass the object to the view.

Try by

```
return View::make('users.index')->with('users', $users);
```

Comment: @mithunsatheesh-- thanks, but I'm not having a problem getting the data to the view-- I'm just asking what the best practice is: sending the ORM object or converting to array first.

Comment: you dont need to convert. you can directly pass the object. then why you need a type conversion in middle?

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

```
$users  = Users::all();
return View::make('users.index')->with(array('users' => $users));
```

or even

```
return View::make('users.index')->with(array('users' => Users::all()));
```

in this case.

You don't need to convert your object to array. In your view (Blade or not) you can display object properties and not array elements and it's really fine to do that. Moreover you can also use [accessor](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators) if you have set any and if you convert your object to array you won't be able to do that